# .Net/c# Wrapper class for Delphi Application

Tags: c#, delphi, interop

I have source code for Delphi application. I need to access the methods in the Delphi source from a C# application. My actual requirement is to create C# wrapper class on Delphi methods, So that I can call it from dot net application. Can you please help me to write C# wrapper on Delphi code?

Comment: Is this related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/8653479/293712  Atleast you can get some hints

Comment: @ Maheep , Thanks for the response. It did not match with my requirement.

Comment: Your questions are too broad. We can help but we aren't going to do the entire job for you. Ask one specific question about one problem at a time. First question may well be on how to implement callbacks since that's your main problem.

Comment: @ David Heffernan, thanks for your Response. I don't have access to edit the Delphi source files. But I can use those files. So I need to write wrapper dll in C#. If I get templates or step by step procedures or links It will be very Helpful for me

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your response to the question that Maheep asked. I thought you meant that that other question was indeed the same issue that you are talking about in this question. I now suspect that this is not the case and that my now deleted answer was addressing the wrong problem. As I stated in the now deleted answer, your question lacks detail and you will not get specific answers to your specific problems until you supply that detail. Please edit the question to provide that detail.

Answer (score 1):

Hydra from RemObjects might be a solution to your problem (i haven't tried it):
http://www.remobjects.com/hydra/

Hydra makes it possible to use native Delphi methods in a .NET application and use .NET methods in af Delphi application.

Answer (score 1):

I have did that by creating Web service from Delphi and call it from c#.

another solution to write Delphi Com DLL and use it in C#.