# PInvoke & Delphi

Tags: c#, delphi, pinvoke

How can i use this dll function in c#? I tried the following but i get error. 
"External component has thrown an exception."

First time i am doing this PInvoke stuff with C# and Delphi.

```
function HTTPGET(location:string):string; stdcall;
var
HTTP:TIdHttp;
begin
  HTTP := TidHttp.Create(nil);
  try
    result := HTTP.Get(location);
  finally
  FreeAndNil(HTTP);
  end;
end;


exports
  HTTPGET;

begin
end.


namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("project1.dll")]
        public static extern string HTTPGET(string location);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(HTTPGET("http://www.reuters.com/"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure the HTTP.Get() works properly with the test address?

Comment: @thalm thats just a test sample website address :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot call that function from C#. That's because you cannot use Delphi `string` for interop. You can use `PAnsiChar` for strings passed from managed to unmanaged, but in the other direction it's more complex. You'd need to allocate the memory at the caller, or use a shared heap. I prefer the latter approach which is easiest done with the COM `BSTR`. This is `WideString` in Delphi.

As has been [discussed before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349530/why-can-a-widestring-not-be-used-as-a-function-return-value-for-interop), you cannot use `WideString` as a return value for interop, since Delphi uses a different ABI from MS tools for return values.

The Delphi code needs to look like this:

```
procedure HTTPGET(URL: PAnsiChar; out result: WideString); stdcall;
```

On the C# side you write it like this:

```
[DllImport("project1.dll")] 
public static extern void HTTPGET(
    string URL,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    out string result
);
```

If you want Unicode for the URL then use `PWideChar` and `CharSet.Unicode`.

```
procedure HTTPGET(URL: PWideChar; out result: WideString); stdcall;
....
[DllImport("project1.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)] 
public static extern void HTTPGET(
    string URL,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    out string result
);
```

Comment: How would it differ from a function?

Comment: I added a link to the answer. It's quite complex.

Comment: Much easier and does the same thing. Fantastic.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, could you explain when and where the memory allocated for the widestring is freed? Thanks.

Comment: @AJ. It is allocated in the Delphi code, and deallocated in the C# code. You don't need to worry about it at all because the frameworks do it for you. Since it is a `BSTR` then the memory is from the shared COM heap, which is why you can allocate and deallocate in different modules.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `string` type: strings require memory management, and C# and Delphi modules obviously use different memory managers (leave alone that C# passes `char*` and Delphi expects `String`). Try changing `location` type to PChar in your DLL, and also change your result type so it's either PChar (the buffer should be allocated explicitly) or something else, but not `string`.

Comment: You've glossed right over the issue of heap deallocation. Use PChar return value, and then what? And on the C# side? You can have C# `string` return value if the native code returns `PChar` allocated with `CoTaskMemAlloc`. But you've really got to cover all bases in detail in a question like this. It's interop. It only works when both sides of the interop divide are aligned.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Is there some guide for more complex interop between Delphi and C# ? Or is Hydra the solution for more complex stuff.

Comment: @t0xic There's not actually a single really good guide for p/invoke and very little if anything on p/invoke with Delphi. Personally I do interop by writing my own p/invokes. Once you know what you are doing it's not hard.

Comment: @t0xic I don't doubt that. I like to do this kind of stuff myself, but I can see that others would be right to choose a different way.

Answer (score -1):

As i remember, you can't marshall delphi strings with C#... you have to use a workaround with PChar and manage the memory yourself, or use something like the workaround provided in the last answer here:

[Using Delphi's stuct arrays and strings in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584690/using-delphis-stuct-arrays-and-strings-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @t0xic I changed it back because your edit completely changed the question

Answer (score -1):

Try Unmanaged Exports for c# by Robert Giesecke

https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports

we are using encrypting engine from c# in Delphi App due compatibility with php and works well (so, the mentioned strings problem do not exists).

our earlier solution (worse) : register c# dll as com component and use it. with above solution output library have to be placed in exe directory and without registration works well :)

Comment: @Lightning UnmanagedExports is wonderful, but it's the solution to a completely different problem.